# Magento 2: Create a custom module for banner slider

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, custom, banner-slider

I want to create a custom module for banner slider in Magento 2. Could anyone please guide me?

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-banner-slider

Comment: How to create it without using third party extension?

Comment: use already developed [magento 2 banner slider](https://www.mageants.com/responsive-banner-slider-extension-for-magento-2.html) extension try it

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing some links with you, i hope you'll find it helpful, you can also customize as per you need, also you can see tutorials of them, in case you wanna learn how to make it yourself.

[Magento 2 Banner Slider Extension FREE by Mageplaza](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-banner-slider)

[Banners Slider Extension For Magento 2 By PHP-Cuong](https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-banners-slider)

[PHP-Cuong Youtube Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwxtiEwEZpk&list=PL98CDCbI3TNvvb0SvN_M35IToppFCHGg3)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I will try

Comment: @SIVAKUMARTN If u find it useful please mark it as solution.